# Is there any way to open ANY page in a iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

So web sites dont allow to open their pages in a iframe for security reasons ----

so I am looking to:

1: the more difficult bit: is there any way to bypass this "not allowed" an still open that page inside our iframe?

2: or is there any possible way to laetr our users for the impossibility to open that page? I say this becasue now what happens is that when we open a page that is not allowed it still open the page in same window or tab we are,  and this causes the user to leave our site page and "forced to that page we are trying to open, and this page will open, but not in iframe mode--

Comment: How are is the framing blocked? Via Javascript? Via the HTTP header?

Answer (score 0):

> 1: the more difficult bit: is there
>   any way to bypass this "not allowed"
>   an still open that page inside our
>   iframe?

No, not really.  The site you are embedding is probably checking with JavaScript to see if it is being embedded, and redirecting the top-level window to their site if so.

If a site doesn't want to let you embed it, don't embed it.  Open it in a new window.

Comment: but is there any way for us to  know that a particular site does not allow  embedding?  what I would like do then is  just give an alert message to our users saying we can not open that page, otherwise the redirect will happen and we are forced out our pour site- and I would not this to happen --

Comment: Yes, *sort of*.  You would have to write JavaScript that would: 1. Open a new window. 2. Insert an iframe into that window with the destination you want. 3. If, after a few seconds, the window gets navigated away from your test page, the site doesn't allow embedding.